# delete data with linkbutton in gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i am using grid view for bulk data, the data is appearing perfectly but i want the delete button to be workable i.e the delete button in each row as shown below[image]

and for this i am using 
`MySqlDataAdapter adp = web_pages.start_page.database.getCriminalsByName(n);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adp.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }`

HTML CODE :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" style="margin-top: 27px; color: #FFFFFF;" Width="502px">
            <Columns>
                <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" ButtonType="Button">
                <ControlStyle BackColor="Transparent" BorderColor="Transparent" ForeColor="White" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="Transparent" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="Transparent" />
                <ItemStyle BackColor="#242529" BorderWidth="0px" />
                </asp:ButtonField>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True">
                <ControlStyle ForeColor="White" />
                </asp:CommandField>
                <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Select" HeaderText="Victim Details" ShowHeader="True" Text="View Victims">
                <ControlStyle BackColor="Transparent" BorderColor="Transparent" ForeColor="White" />
                </asp:ButtonField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

so can any one help to find the index of that row or any other method.

Comment: Post the html mark-up of your gridview.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RowCommand Event of Gridview

inside gridview

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" CommandName="dede" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>'>Delete</asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
```

In CS page you can call RowCommand Event

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

            if (e.CommandName == "dede")
            {

                int i = 0;
//BLL.DBClass is my Custom Connection Class
                i = BLL.DBClass.ExecNonQueryInt("delete from table where id=" + Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument) + "", null, false);



            }

           }
```

Comment: Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument) saying error i.e input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>'>  inside Eval what value are you passing and please show me the query that you have written

Answer (score 0):

One small mistake just replace CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>' , because there is additional '>' in the solution given by Akhil.